# how to narrow the type for SVG Element union

Tags: reactjs, typescript, svg

I am using react to set a reference to an svg element that might be a `<rect>`, `<polygon>` or `<ellipse>`.

I have this declaration:

```
const shapeRef = useRef<SVGPolygonElement | SVGEllipseElement | SVGRectElement>(null);
```

But when I try and set this on an `<ellipse>` element like this:

```
<ellipse
  cx={width / 8}
  cy={-sideDimension(y) / 8}
  rx={width}
  ry={height}
  ref={shapeRef}
/>
```

I get this error:

> Type 'RefObject' is not assignable to type 'string | ((instance:
>   SVGEllipseElement | null) => void) | RefObject |
>   null | undefined'.   Type 'RefObject' is not assignable to type
>   'RefObject'.
>       Type 'SVGPolygonElement | SVGEllipseElement | SVGRectElement' is not assignable to type 'SVGEllipseElement'.
>         Type 'SVGPolygonElement' is missing the following properties from type 'SVGEllipseElement': cx, cy, rx, ryts(2322)

My understanding from this is that I somehow need to narrow the type in order for this to work or else every object that uses this ref must have all properties of the union.

Comment: did you see my answer? did it help? let me know if you need further assistant

Comment: if you can please communicate if my answer didn't help so I can change it. the grace period ends in 10 hours

Comment: @Thatkookooguy you should have the bounty now, let me know if you don't get it

Comment: thx! got it :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are correct. Typescript gives you that error because it doesn't know which one of the types it should account the `shapreRef` as.

The best solution IMO is using a [Type Guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html). A **Type Guard** is the typescript way to check if a variable is of a certain type. For union types, that gives typescript the understanding that something is of a specific type.

For example, in your case, it can be something like this:

```ts
interface IEllipse {
  attr1: string;
  attr2: string;
}

interface IRect {
  attr3: string;
  attr4: string;
}

type SvgShape = IEllipse | IRect | IPolygon;

function isEllipse(shape: SvgShape): shape is IEllipse {
    return (shape as IEllipse).attr1 !== undefined;
}
```

Notice that the return type is `shape is IEllipse`. This means that typescript will interpret a truthy return value here as if `shape` **is an `IEllipse`**.

Then, wherever you want to use a `SvgShape`, you can check which type of `SvgShape` it is and typescript should know the type based on that:

```ts
// ...
render() {
  const shape: SvgShape = this.getCurrentShape();

  if (isEllipse(shape)) {
    // typescript should KNOW that this is an ellipse inside this if
    // it will accept all of Ellipse's attribute and reject other attributes
    // that appear in other shapes

    return <ellipse .../>;
  } else if (isRect(shape)) {
    // typescript should interpet this shape as a Rect inside the `if`

    return <rect ... />;
  } else {
    // typescript will know only one subtype left (IPolygon)

    return <polygon points="..." />;
  }
}
// ...
```

#### Why not just an Intersection type?

Well... Intersection types are more for cases where every one of the types (Rect, Polygon, etc) have the exact same attributes in the new item.
For example:

```ts
type Inter = IRect & IPolygon & IEllipse;
```

Means that an `Inter` type is `IRect` and `IPolygon` and `IEllipse`. That means an object of this type will have all members of all three types.
So, trying to access the attribute `points` (which exists on `IPolygon`) on a shape that is actually an `IRect`, will act as if that attribute exists there (which we don't want)

You will mostly see intersection types used for mixins and other concepts that don’t fit in the classic object-oriented mold.

#### how to use with useRef?

```ts
type SvgShape = SVGPolygonElement | SVGEllipseElement | SVGRectElement;

const shapeRef = useRef<SvgShape>(null);

function isEllipseRef(shapeRef: MutableRefObject<SvgShape>): shapeRef is MutableRefObject<IEllipse> {
  const shape: SvgShape = shapeRef.current;
  return (shape as IEllipse).attr1 !== undefined;
}
```