# How to refine the value of a property on an object in typescript?

Tags: typescript

Is there any way to refine a property on an object?

```
declare const a: {
  x?: number
};

if (a.x) {
  doSomething(a); // how do I refine `a.x` here to `number`?
}
```

I realize the reason for it, and know that I can assign `a.x` to a const, but I want to pass the entire `a` object and tell TS that `a.x` is no longer possibly `undefined`

Comment: Relevant Github issue [Microsoft/TypeScript#30506](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30506)... type guards on properties don't usually narrow parent/grandparent/ancestor objects, probably [for performance reasons](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/9163#issuecomment-226241452)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a generic solution, here's a slight adjustment to @AlekseyL.'s proposal:

```
function has<T extends {}, K extends keyof T>(a: T, k: K): a is T & { [k in K]-?: T[K] } {
  return typeof a[k] !== "undefined";
}

declare const a: {
  x?: number
};

if (has(a, "x")) {
  doSomething(a);
}
```

---

Even More Generic™ solution:

```
function has<T extends object, K extends keyof T>(
  obj: T,
  ...props: K[]
): obj is T & { [k in K]-?: NonNullable<T[K]> } {
  for (const prop in props) {
    if (obj[prop] === null || obj[prop] === undefined) return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, will use this with the minor tweak of adding `NonNullable<T[K]>` as well

Comment: Actualy tweaking a bit more.  Same thing, it just allows checking any number of props against `null | undefined` (sorry for the horrid spacing in comments): `export function hasProps<T extends object, K extends keyof T>(
  obj: T,
  ...props: K[]
): obj is T & { [k in K]-?: NonNullable<T[K]> } {
  for (const prop in props) {
    if (obj[prop] === null || obj[prop] === undefined) return false;
  }

  return true;
}`

Answer (score 2):

### The Partial Type

The easiest way to do this is to use the [`Partial` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#mapped-types). It allows you to map an existing type to a similar type with all attributes marked as optional.

then, when you call `doSomething`, tell typescript that now `a` can be treated as a full item with casting.

```ts
interface Item {
  x: number
}

const a: Partial<Item> = {};

if (a.x) {
  doSomething(a as Item);
}

function doSomething(item: Item) { /* ... */ }
```

This will tell typescript to reference `a` as a "Partial Item".

### Using Type Guards with Partial

If you want to avoid the casting at the end and use typescript mechanisms to know `a` is a full type, you can use a [Type Guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html). That way, you don't need to tell typescript to treat `a as Item`.

```ts
interface Item {
  x: number
}

const a: Partial<Item> = {};

if (isItemComplete(a)) {
  doSomething(a);
}

function doSomething(item: Item) { /* ... */ }

function isItemComplete(item: Partial<Item>): item is Item {
  return !!item.x; // <-- make sure everything exists on item
}
```

When we call `isItemComplete` inside the `if`, typescript **knows** that inside the `if`'s scope, `a` is definetly a complete `Item` and not a `Partial<Item>`. Outside of that `if`, typescript will continue to treat `a` as a `Partial<Item>`.

Comment: Nice copy with explanation ;)

Comment: @AlekseyL. the second part of my answer? I actually copied that from [another answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56378450/1788884). It just happens to be similar :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) for this:

```
declare const a: {
  x?: number
};

if (hasX(a)) {
  doSomething(a); // a is of type { x: number } here
}

function hasX(a: { x?: number }): a is { x: number } {
  return !!a.x;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=declare%20const%20a%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20x%3F%3A%20number%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aif%20(hasX(a))%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20doSomething(a)%3B%20%2F%2F%20how%20do%20I%20refine%20%60a.x%60%20here%20to%20%60number%60%3F%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20hasX(a%3A%20%7B%20x%3F%3A%20number%20%7D)%3A%20a%20is%20%7B%20x%3A%20number%20%7D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20!!a.x%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20function%20doSomething(a)%3B)