# Can type-guards apply to members of an interface?

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```
enum Fruit {
  Apple,
  Banana,
}

interface FruitWrapper {
  fruit: Fruit;
  //...
}

function IOnlyLikeApples(o: FruitWrapper & { fruit: Fruit.Apple }) { ... }
```

and a `switch` as my type-guard

```
const o: ISomeInterface = getFruit();
switch(o.fruit) {
  case Fruit.Apple:
    IOnlyLikeApples(o);
    break;
}
```

I get the following error on passing `o` to `IOnlyLikeApples`:

```
Argument of type 'FruitWrapper' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FruitWrapper & { fruit: Fruit.Apple; }'.
  Type 'FruitWrapper' is not assignable to type '{ fruit: Fruit.Apple; }'.
    Types of property 'fruit' are incompatible.
      Type 'Fruit' is not assignable to type 'Fruit.Apple'.
```

Why is TS complaining about this? There is an argument that even though the reference `o` is constant, its members are not, but `o.fruit` is not being reassigned.  Even if I use `interface FruitWrapper { readonly fruit: Fruit; }`, TS still rejects this code.

The only solution I can think of is something like the following,

```
const o: ISomeInterface = getFruit();
const f = o.fruit;
switch(f) {
  case Fruit.Apple:
    IOnlyLikeApples({ ...o,  fruit: f });
    break;
}
```

which is ugly and gross (and at that point, not worth the compiler support to help the caller of `IOnlyLikeApples`).

`IOnlyLikeApples` has a different maintainer than the `switch`.

Comment: This seems similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/56463927/1443496. Is the type guard here still not automatic?

Answer (score 0):

I kinda got it working but its not that pretty:

```
const getFruit = () => {
  if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
    return {
      fruit: Fruit.Banana,
      misc: 'asd'
    // the as const is needed here. Unfortunate.
    } as const
  } else {
    return {
      fruit: Fruit.Apple,
      misc: 'asd'
    // and here. Unfortunate again.
    } as const
  }
}

const o = getFruit();

switch(o.fruit) {
  case Fruit.Apple:
    IOnlyLikeApples(o);
    break;
  case Fruit.Banana:
    IOnlyLikeApples(o);
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAYgTmAlgFygbwLACgpQIIAOBANsADTa4BCAhiHTRVgL7baIjLBwBmNAxsFgIUAdTg0i3ADwAVKMAAeXEABMAzsKTIAfOkpQeI5AC4osgNwGA9NYB0D7KyzYeYEP2SIA9iCgBJAHkQYgBPABlEAGtgQhJgdQAKbzN4bXFJAhk0lDs40h0ASnQoAyc2LH5fdVQAc2BkHNQAXihE4ua9TBwoRB42gFkaZAALOwk1bwh2qD0ABjsAVmLu3Fw4BrA4P1W13CNtVOM7Wnp6Jj3cCER1fjMAchp1VXuDXGYoJ6gqkBqDD%20AxHUQl2602230PT2BxQR20eSIpAul2utweTxebygHy%20Pz%20PWczmweNQ3igrXqjWM7SsLiw6gA7ih%20CNknYYcgVgZ%20E8hE0EfETFigiEItFYoiEslCrS9gAjDY0KKy768rS5U4MIVQgLBMKRGL5KXeGXlOlAA)

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this problem before when attempting to use a switch as a type guard.  It's down to the fact that typescript assigns the type to the object `o` at the beginning of the switch and never re-evaluates it.  If you look at the values of `o` and `o.fruit` within the `case Fruit.Apple` branch, you'll see that TS knows that `o.fruit` is of type `Fruit.Apple`, but still considers the type of `o` to be `FruitWrapper` and hasn't added anything else to it.

There's a bunch of ways to address this.  The easiest and sloppiest is to simply assert what you know: `IOnlyLikeApples(o as FruitWrapper & { fruit: Fruit.Apple });`

Do you have to use a switch statement?  If you can rewrite it with a type guard inside of an `if` then you won't have this issue.

```
type Apple = FruitWrapper & { fruit: Fruit.Apple };

const isApple = (o: FruitWrapper): o is Apple => {
    return o.fruit === Fruit.Apple;
}

const handleFruit = ( o: FruitWrapper ) => {
    if ( isApple(o) ) {
        IOnlyLikeApples(o);
    } else {
        /*...*/
    }
}
```

The other option, which may or may not make sense depending on your data, is for fruit to be a union type.  `switch` falls short at specifying within an interface, but it is able to handle discriminating within a union.  This works fine:

```
type Apple = FruitWrapper & { fruit: Fruit.Apple };

type Banana = FruitWrapper & { fruit: Fruit.Banana };

type FruitUnion = Apple | Banana;

const handleFruit = ( o: FruitUnion ) => {
    switch(o.fruit) {
        case Fruit.Apple:
            IOnlyLikeApples(o);
            break;
        case Fruit.Banana:
            /* ... */
            break;
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.7#code/KYOwrgtgBAYgTmAlgFygbwFBSgQQA54A2wANFlAEICGINVZAvhhoiMsHAGZUDGwsCFAHU4VAh3TlOg5AC4BSZAG5yAelUA6LRiYZkATzz98RfgF4Fw0eLhQAZOijTF8%20Io0niUBioycwIDzIiAD2IFAAkgDyIIT6ADKIANbAnsAAzgAUIfJpUACUkro8YemoiOl5FtmuMiJiRnD58iFQFbgEXmYAfJLY2HDAyGBw4SEazihQZjOWyB6dwCrFpagAFjQAJsRuKACM01CZUDlz9TYF072Y-W2cR22Vi9mFhTe3-dGxCcmpi1khfIqW4MKDAQjpfjvD5QVQAKi0GjhqnI2CYugMRkodFoh12yHOjXsjkmcjmGmotFxPmYmP4%20IAqiBQuELHkAD7YqlUXwlEBlKAbEDbYD4gBMh2Op0ZzLClx6fX66QA7igeGtshMZG9UR8eFRIeS0rJdTDsF84okUmkAUDTWaAEaDKhJYFm-WG-EUnFUE1mj7wqCIqDI%200wp3AF1utE6IA)