# 'Refining' the allowed values of a property in an interface

Tags: typescript

Related to [Can type-guards apply to members of an interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64053292/1443496), is there a better way to define a type or interface where `fruit` is specifically `Fruit.Apple` that is resilient to `fruit` being renamed upstream?

```
// upstream
enum Fruit {
  Apple,
  Banana,
}

interface FruitWrapper {
  fruit: Fruit;
  //...
}

// my stuff
function IOnlyLikeApples(o: FruitWrapper & { fruit: Fruit.Apple }) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can make FruitWrapper generic

```
interface FruitWrapper <T extends Fruit> {
  fruit: T;
  //...
}

// my stuff
function IOnlyLikeApples(o: FruitWrapper<Fruit.Apple>) {  }
```

Comment: Beat me by ten seconds :-) I only added the default type value: `<T extends Fruit = Fruit>`. This solution is much nicer! but I'm interested in what others may say.

Comment: Sorry:) If you want a default value, then it should be `T extends Fruit = Fruit.Apple` I guess

Comment: Having the default be `Fruit` (most general) would fit most use-cases better here (esp. when there are many values in `Fruit` that are all equally likely), but you're right on here :-)